# SEO URL Structure

Tags: url-rewriting, url-routing, seo

Based on the following example URL structure:

mysite.com/mypage.aspx?a=red&b=green&c=blue

Pages in the application use ASP.net user controls and some of these controls build a query string.  To prevent duplicate keys being created e.g. &pid=12&pid=10, I am researching methods of rewriting the URL:

a)

mysite.com/mypage.aspx/red/green/blue

b)

mysite.com/mypage.aspx?controlname=a,red|b,green|c,blue

Pages using this structure would be publishing content that I would like to get indexed and ranked - articles and products (8,000 products to start, with thousands more being added later)

My gut instinct tells me to go with the first method, but would it would be overkill to add all that infrastructure if the second method will accomplish my goal of getting pages indexed AND ranked.

So my question, looking at the pro's and con's, Google Ranking, time to implement etc. which method should I use?

Thanks!

Comment: You can even shorten it further: mysite.com/red/green/blue

Comment: Good you asked about advice for the implementation. Otherwise this question wouldn’t be that much programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an SEO perspective you want to try and avoid the querystring, so getting it into the URL and a short form URL is going to get you a better "bang for the buck" on the implementation side of things.

Therefore, I'd recommend the first.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use MVC pattern, this way all your link will be SEO ready. Check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), you will find what is MVC and also some implementation in .net!

Comment: Because this is already a mature system that has been in production for many years.

Comment: Ok the se this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx, here will found about url rewriteing in asp .net

Comment: What does the MVC pattern have to do with SEO urls? The MVC pattern doesn't guarantee/prescribe the availabilty/implementation of SEO friendly urls.

Comment: All link when you use MVC will be like this www.example.com/controlerx/actiony/paramz that is more SEO than www.example.com?controler=x&action=y&parm=z also if you will use a kind of slug in database for a place in page you will can process it so it will redirect it to corect page: www.example.com/slugx can be interpreted like www.example.com/controlerx/actiony/paramz, so MVC is a good start for SEO ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make SEO-friendly URLs with the help of [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/) (the software which allows having basic Apache functionality on your IIS server). You'll need mod_rewrite I guess.
If you get interested, I can help you with the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain in more detail your current architecture and what the parameters all mean? There's nothing really wrong with query strings if it's truly dynamic content. Rewriting `?a=red&b=green&c=blue` to `/red/green/blue` is kinda pointless and it's unclear from the URL what might be on the page.

The key is to **simplify** as much as possible. Split the site into categories and give each "entity" one URL.

For example, if you are selling products, use one URL per product, with keywords in the URL - e.g. `mysite.com/products/red-widget` or `mysite.com/products/12-red-widget` if you need the product ID.